# Absence of Coulomb's force

Tags: electrostatics, cosmology, universe, coulombs-law, supernova

I am interested in understanding the **potential consequences if Coulomb's force were to suddenly vanish** on the behavior and interactions of various objects. If this fundamental force suddenly ceases to exist in the universe, how would it affect the behavior of particles and their interactions? Furthermore, what implications would this have for the **overall functioning of the universe**? I am particularly interested in gaining insights into the **cosmological consequences** of such a scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Without the electrostatic interaction, there would be no atom (electrons are bounded to the nucleus by the electrostatic interaction) and therefore, no molecule, no chemistry and no biology. The universe would still be a plasma and would still be opaque (no Cosmic Microwave Background).